# Syntax Error "Expecting expression, got '<'" while trying to run reactjs tutorial

Tags: reactjs

I am working through the reactjs tutorial using my own server (apache) and the suggested HTML file and verbatim copy of tutorial examples ...

The simplest example fails on my server but works on JSFiddle ..

My HTML file with script is shown below ..

the script fails with a syntax error at the render: function() { ...

Error message in firefox and Safari (mac version, latest ) ..

""" SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' 
React.render(, document.getElementById('container')
"""
[My File ]

```
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/marked/0.3.2/marked.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/react.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<script>
var Hello = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
    }
});

React.render(<Hello name="World" />, document.getElementById('container'));

</script>

<body>

    <div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try moving the `<script></script>` tags to inside the body. The JSX transformer script needs time to load.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There are two issues with the code you've posted.

The first is that the JSX transformer is not transforming your code because the appropriate `type` attribute is not present on the `script` tag.

Change

```javascript
<script>
var Hello = React.createClass({
...
```

to

```javascript
<script type="text/jsx">
var Hello = React.createClass({
...
```

Secondly, you're calling `document.getElementById('container')` before that `div` actually exists on the page; move that final `script` tag and its contents to after the `div` (e.g., to the bottom of the `body`).

You should end up with code that is similar to how it's shown in the tutorial:

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello React</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script type="text/jsx">
      // Your code here
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you -- I see now .. It works this way and makes complete sense why it couldn't work before

Comment: This didn't work for me. I get blank screen. No console errors.

Comment: I tried but didn't work for me, I have added the answer below for my case.

Answer (score 2):

i had same problem and the problem was

`npm init`

after i ran this it asks some kind of questions and fills data into `package.json` and changes `homepage` and other stuff i just opened package.json and removed all that lines which is created by npm at the end of file like `description,homepage,author`

Comment: As surprised as I was, this turned out to be the answer to me, as I was trying to recreate a project from scratch, with the least version pinning as possible for dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing the same error when using react via cdn in my html file and i stumbled upon this post which looks quite similar to my problem.

The problem with my code was that the js was unable to understand jsx code used by me in my components render method.

Here is how i got it fixed.
other than react i added another cdn for babel-standalone like this

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.24.0/babel.js"></script>
```

along with changing `type="text/javascript"` to `type="text/babel"` on script tag wrapping my js code.

```
<script type="text/babel">/* my react code containing jsx */</script>
```

***Posting this answer in hope it might help someone facing the same issue.***

Answer (score 1):

This is an old thread, but I ran into this error recently when I did an npm run build on my React app and just copied it over from a Windows box to a Linux Box using WinSCP.  I am using nginx to serve the app on the Linux box.  Turns out my problem was that there was not execute permissions on the JS files in the static directory.  This caused an error and just served my index.html instead of the js file, hence the SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'.  Hopefully this will help someone who stumbles onto this thread in the future.
Just run `chmod -R 755 static` from the app's directory

Answer (score 1):

Narsters's answer worked for me, but I had to add this line to my package.json

```
 "homepage": "./",
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a newbie to react added to Website. I find the demo code in https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html
and the code in [codepen](https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/VmmPgp?editors=0010) is different.

I download the code from codepen. It's this: (It works)

```
  render() {
    return (
      React.createElement("form", { onSubmit: this.handleSubmit },
      React.createElement("label", null, "Name:",
      React.createElement("input", { type: "text", value: this.state.value, onChange: this.handleChange })),
      React.createElement("input", { type: "submit", value: "Submit" }))
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
React.createElement(NameForm, null),
document.getElementById('root'));
```

And the code in official site is this: (It doesn't work)

```
    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <label>
                    Name:
                    <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                </label>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <NameForm />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I don't know why they are different, but I only know I should use methods instead of tags

Comment: I think the "tags" method is JSX, and won't work in a browser (in 2020) without a preprocess step.  If you go to "Settings->Js" in CodePen, and select 'Babel" as the JavaScript Preprocessor, you should be able to use the "tags" method.  Select "None" as the preprocessor, and you should get "SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'".  Outside of CodePen, you would use a bundler, like webpack, to perform the transpile.

Answer (score 0):

There can be different reasons for this issue.
One is already answered by @Michelle Tilley on top

Make sure you have checked and tried above the first solution.

So let me explain what was the reason in my case.

I missed using `%PUBLIC_URL%` in my `index.html` file and that was the reason I was facing this issue.

`index.html`
let say you have imported the files for layout and Js like used below.

```
<script src="/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

this will create error such as

```
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' jquery.min.js:1
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' bootstrap.bundle.min.js:1
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' js.cookie.js:1
```

to solve this issue. you need to import files properly by using `%PUBLIC_URL%`  e.g

```
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/vendor/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this will help others. Cheers